# File Path Not Working for Sharing Audio File Via Intent

Tags: android, firebase, mp3, share

I am trying to this for **3 days** and whole I want to do is that send audio files which are on firebase storage. But before send it I have to download it. **There is no problem about downloading** but unfortunatelly I cant share it by using intent. Here is the code to downloading->

```
private void getFileUrl() {
        final StorageReference refGulus = storage.getReference().child("gulus.mp3");

        refGulus.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                downloadFiles(context, "Mobile", ".mp3",Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, uri);
            }
        });

    }

         public void downloadFiles(Context context, String fileName, String fileExtention, String destinationDirectory, Uri uri)
         {
                    DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, destinationDirectory, fileName+fileExtention);
                    downloadManager.enqueue(request);

//Maybe the problem is in these 2 lines in below I dont know.
             final File file1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),""+fileName+fileExtention);
             myUri = Uri.fromFile(file1); // (myUri is declarated as static in upper so no problem to use it to other classes) 
         }
```

And here is the DownloadBroadcastReceiver to understand the download is finished and ready to sharing ->

```
import static dem.ersin.idrisustaa.Adapters.FirebaseToRecyclerAdapter.myUri;

public class DownloadBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("audio/*");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, myUri);
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));
    }
}
```

And here is the error for Whatsapp and gmail:

> File format is not supported

This error from vlc media player when I try to open it

> file:///Android/data/dem.ersin.idrisustaa/files/Download/Mobile.mp3 location cannot be played

When I manually go to phone's storage and try to play the Mobile.mp3 it plays well. There is a problem about path in my opinion.

Where is the problem? What do you think?

Comment: Your app should be crashing with a `FileUriExposedException`. `Uri.fromFile()` has been banned in effect for about 5 years. Use `FileProvider` and `getUriForFile()`.